# Load particular view to a region at runtime

Tags: wpf, module, prism

I am facing a problem in my prism application. I have one region "Main Region". There are some 5 views registered for this main region. But when I start the application, only one particular view "Dashboard" should be shown as default view. but the problem is there are other views getting loaded as default view.

How do I make Dashobard as my default view when I start the application?

I tried with Module Dependency but it didn't work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to register all the modules with the regions. LAter I discovered when I navigate by default modules will get registered to the regions. So I removed the registerviewwithregion code from all the modules apart from Dashboard

Thanks,
Sabaresh

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the module which has the dashboard view is the only module marked with **onDemand = false** 
If all the views live in the same module then you have to register the views with the region on demand so that only the dashboard view get registered on module initialization and the other views get registered depending on the user interaction with the UI